# Is it too late to upgrade from 18.04?

Tags: upgrade

I know I'm way ***way*** behind but it's finally time to upgrade my 18.04 system as some things just don't work properly anymore.  There's no fool like an old fool and I waited too long.  I usually *don't fix what ain't broke* but it's a problem now.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I've read versions of this question and tried the answers but I'm getting nowhere.  I can't even get past **apt update**:

`% sudo apt update`

[apt update screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mppq.png)

Is it hopeless?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/msantic), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: After a release goes EOL (or EOSS), mirrors & 3rd party repositories are free to *drop* support for the release, thus issues are to be expected. You should still be able to *release-upgrade* your system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*that would be on-topic on this site!*) as per documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades) though that release-upgrade maybe harder now; but that's not what your question asks help with  (FYI: You should be expected to *release-upgrade* until 20.04 reaches EOSS in 2025-April)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting for it instead. From what I can tell, it just seems like a bunch of third party repos that are erroring out, but that shouldn't prevent you from upgrading to 20.04.

Comment: muru, I did copy the text but it was rejected because there were too many links.  I changed all the links so they weren't valid URLs but then was it was rejected since it "looked like spam... hence the screenshot.

Comment: Use [code block]s for command output, links in code formatting are not treated as links.